# edit text not loading url into webview and app crashes on button press

Tags: android, url, android-edittext, android-webview, webviewclient

fellow noob here having problems with my first app. What i am trying to achieve is to have Edit Text in the Action Bar which would accept and user typed URL and load it in the webview preferably without a go button and on keyboard enter only, but cant get it to work either way. The app is supposed to work like a browser. I have tried many things and nothing seems to work even assigned a button and app crashes. Have been trying to figure it out for the last 62hrs...:( Would really appreciate some help and any way i can go about making this work.

Here is the code:

MainActivity

```
package com.example.------------;

import android.app.Activity;

import android.app.ActionBar;
import android.app.Fragment;
import android.app.FragmentManager;
import android.app.SearchManager;
import android.content.Context;
import android.os.Build;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.view.Gravity;
import android.view.LayoutInflater;
import android.view.Menu;
import android.view.MenuInflater;
import android.view.MenuItem;
import android.view.View;
import android.view.ViewGroup;
import android.support.v4.widget.DrawerLayout;
import android.widget.ArrayAdapter;
import android.widget.TextView;
import android.widget.TextView.OnEditorActionListener;
import android.app.Activity;
import android.view.KeyEvent;
import android.view.View.OnClickListener;
import android.view.inputmethod.EditorInfo;
import android.view.inputmethod.InputMethodManager;
import android.webkit.CookieManager;
import android.webkit.WebChromeClient;
import android.webkit.WebSettings;
import android.webkit.WebSettings.PluginState;
import android.webkit.WebView;
import android.webkit.WebViewClient;
import android.widget.Button;
import android.widget.EditText;
import android.widget.ListView;
import android.widget.PopupMenu;
import android.widget.ProgressBar;
import android.widget.SearchView;
import android.widget.SearchView.OnQueryTextListener;
import android.widget.Toast;



public class MainActivity extends Activity 

    implements NavigationDrawerFragment.NavigationDrawerCallbacks{

/**
 * Fragment managing the behaviors, interactions and presentation of the     navigation drawer.
 */
private NavigationDrawerFragment mNavigationDrawerFragment;

/**
 * Used to store the last screen title. For use in {@link #restoreActionBar()}.
 */
private CharSequence mTitle;
private WebView webView;
private EditText field;
private ProgressBar progress;
private InputMethodManager mIMEMgr;


@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
    ActionBar actionBar = getActionBar();
    actionBar.setDisplayOptions(ActionBar.DISPLAY_SHOW_CUSTOM
            | ActionBar.DISPLAY_SHOW_HOME);
    // add the custom view to the action bar
    actionBar.setCustomView(R.layout.actionbar_view);


    field = (EditText)findViewById(R.id.urlField);
    webView = (WebView)findViewById(R.id.webView1);
    webView.setWebChromeClient(new MyWebViewClient());




Button openUrl = (Button) findViewById(R.id.button1);
openUrl.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener() {
     @Override
        public void onClick(View view) {
            String url = field.getText().toString();
             String prefix = "https://www.google.com/search?q=";
             if(!url.startsWith("http://") && !url.startsWith("https://")  && !url.endsWith(".com"))
             {
                 url = prefix + url;
             }

             if(url.endsWith(".com") || url.endsWith(".as") || url.endsWith(".uk") || url.endsWith(".biz"))

             {
                 if(!url.startsWith("http://") && !url.startsWith("https://"))
                 {
                     url = "http://" + url;
                 }
             }
            if (validateUrl(url)) {
                webView.getSettings().setJavaScriptEnabled(true);
                webView.loadUrl(url);

                MainActivity.this.progress.setProgress(0);
            }

        }

        private boolean validateUrl(String url) {
            return true;

        }
    });




    mNavigationDrawerFragment = (NavigationDrawerFragment)
            getFragmentManager().findFragmentById(R.id.navigation_drawer);
    mTitle = getTitle();

    // Set up the drawer.
    mNavigationDrawerFragment.setUp(
            R.id.navigation_drawer,
            (DrawerLayout) findViewById(R.id.drawer_layout));


        }




@Override
public void onNavigationDrawerItemSelected(int position) {
    // update the main content by replacing fragments
    FragmentManager fragmentManager = getFragmentManager();
    fragmentManager.beginTransaction()
            .replace(R.id.container, PlaceholderFragment.newInstance(position + 1))
            .commit();
}

public void onSectionAttached(int number) {
    switch (number) {
        case 1:
            mTitle = getString(R.string.title_section1);
            break;
        case 2:
            mTitle = getString(R.string.title_section2);
            break;
        case 3:
            mTitle = getString(R.string.title_section3);
            break;
    }
}

public void restoreActionBar() {
    ActionBar actionBar = getActionBar();
    actionBar.setDisplayShowTitleEnabled(false);
    actionBar.setTitle(mTitle);
}


private class MyWebViewClient extends WebChromeClient {
private class HelloWebViewClient extends WebViewClient {
    @Override
    public boolean shouldOverrideUrlLoading(WebView View, String url)
    {


    webView.loadUrl(url);
    return true;
    }
    }
 }
 @Override
 public boolean onKeyDown(int keyCode, KeyEvent event)
 {

 if ((keyCode == KeyEvent.KEYCODE_BACK) && webView.canGoBack())

 {
 webView.goBack();
 return true;
 }
 return super.onKeyDown(keyCode, event);
 }
  @Override
 public boolean onCreateOptionsMenu(Menu menu) {
      MenuInflater inflater = getMenuInflater();




    if (!mNavigationDrawerFragment.isDrawerOpen()) {
        // Only show items in the action bar relevant to this screen
        // if the drawer is not showing. Otherwise, let the drawer
        // decide what to show in the action bar.



        restoreActionBar();
        return true;
    }
    return super.onCreateOptionsMenu(menu);
 }

  protected boolean validateUrl(String url) {
    // TODO Auto-generated method stub
    return false;
  }



  @Override
  public boolean onOptionsItemSelected(MenuItem item) {
    // Handle action bar item clicks here. The action bar will
    // automatically handle clicks on the Home/Up button, so long
    // as you specify a parent activity in AndroidManifest.xml.
    int id = item.getItemId();
    if (id == R.id.action_settings) {
        return true;
    }
    return super.onOptionsItemSelected(item);
  }

 /**
 * A placeholder fragment containing a simple view.
 */
    public static class PlaceholderFragment extends Fragment {
    /**
     * The fragment argument representing the section number for this
     * fragment.
     */
    private static final String ARG_SECTION_NUMBER = "section_number";

    /**
     * Returns a new instance of this fragment for the given section
     * number.
     */
    public static PlaceholderFragment newInstance(int sectionNumber) {
        PlaceholderFragment fragment = new PlaceholderFragment();
        Bundle args = new Bundle();
        args.putInt(ARG_SECTION_NUMBER, sectionNumber);
        fragment.setArguments(args);
        return fragment;
    }

    public PlaceholderFragment() {
    }

    @Override
    public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container,
            Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        View rootView = inflater.inflate(R.layout.fragment_main, container, false);
        return rootView;
    }

    @Override
    public void onAttach(Activity activity) {
        super.onAttach(activity);
        ((MainActivity) activity).onSectionAttached(
                getArguments().getInt(ARG_SECTION_NUMBER));
    }
  }
 }
```

activity_main

```
  <android.support.v4.widget.DrawerLayout                 xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
android:id="@+id/drawer_layout"
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="match_parent"
tools:context="com.example.--------------.MainActivity" >

<!--
     As the main content view, the view below consumes the entire
     space available using match_parent in both dimensions.
-->

<FrameLayout
    android:id="@+id/container"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent" >

     <WebView
         android:id="@+id/webView1"
         android:layout_width="match_parent"
         android:layout_height="250dp"
         android:layout_centerHorizontal="true"
         android:layout_centerVertical="true"
         tools:context=".MainActivity" />

     <Button
android:id="@+id/button1"
android:onClick="onClick"
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="wrap_content"
android:text="Go" />





</FrameLayout>

<!--
     android:layout_gravity="start" tells DrawerLayout to treat
     this as a sliding drawer on the left side for left-to-right
     languages and on the right side for right-to-left languages.
     If you're not building against API 17 or higher, use
     android:layout_gravity="left" instead.
-->
<!--
     The drawer is given a fixed width in dp and extends the full height of
     the container.
-->



<fragment
    android:id="@+id/navigation_drawer"
    android:name="com.example.minimalbrowserx.NavigationDrawerFragment"
    android:layout_width="@dimen/navigation_drawer_width"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
```

actionbar_view

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<EditText xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
android:id="@+id/urlField"
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="match_parent"
android:imeOptions="actionDone"
android:inputType="textFilter"
android:text="no" >

</EditText>
```

Android Manifest

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<manifest xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
package="com.example.------------"
android:versionCode="1"
android:versionName="1.0" >

<uses-sdk
    android:minSdkVersion="16"
    android:targetSdkVersion="21" />
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.INTERNET"/>
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.CHANGE_CONFIGURATION"/>
<application
    android:allowBackup="true"
    android:icon="@drawable/ic_launcher"
    android:label="@string/app_name"
    android:theme="@style/AppTheme" >
    <activity
        android:name=".MainActivity"
        android:label="@string/app_name" >
        <intent-filter>
            <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN" />

            <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER" />
        </intent-filter>
    </activity>
</application>

</manifest>
```

LogCat

```js
03-25 18:52:13.301: D/AndroidRuntime(10241): >>>>>> AndroidRuntime START com.android.internal.os.RuntimeInit <<<<<<
03-25 18:52:13.311: D/AndroidRuntime(10241): CheckJNI is ON
03-25 18:52:13.411: D/dalvikvm(10241): Trying to load lib libjavacore.so 0x0
03-25 18:52:13.421: D/dalvikvm(10241): Added shared lib libjavacore.so 0x0
03-25 18:52:13.441: D/dalvikvm(10241): Trying to load lib libnativehelper.so 0x0
03-25 18:52:13.441: D/dalvikvm(10241): Added shared lib libnativehelper.so 0x0
03-25 18:52:13.441: D/dalvikvm(10241): No JNI_OnLoad found in libnativehelper.so 0x0, skipping init
03-25 18:52:13.711: D/dalvikvm(10241): Note: class Landroid/app/ActivityManagerNative; has 179 unimplemented (abstract) methods
03-25 18:52:14.381: E/memtrack(10241): Couldn't load memtrack module (No such file or directory)
03-25 18:52:14.381: E/android.os.Debug(10241): failed to load memtrack module: -2
03-25 18:52:14.781: D/AndroidRuntime(10241): Calling main entry com.android.commands.pm.Pm
03-25 18:52:14.831: D/AndroidRuntime(10241): Shutting down VM
03-25 18:52:14.831: D/dalvikvm(10241): Debugger has detached; object registry had 1 entries
03-25 18:52:15.631: D/AndroidRuntime(10252): >>>>>> AndroidRuntime START com.android.internal.os.RuntimeInit <<<<<<
03-25 18:52:15.641: D/AndroidRuntime(10252): CheckJNI is ON
03-25 18:52:15.741: D/dalvikvm(10252): Trying to load lib libjavacore.so 0x0
03-25 18:52:15.751: D/dalvikvm(10252): Added shared lib libjavacore.so 0x0
03-25 18:52:15.771: D/dalvikvm(10252): Trying to load lib libnativehelper.so 0x0
03-25 18:52:15.771: D/dalvikvm(10252): Added shared lib libnativehelper.so 0x0
03-25 18:52:15.781: D/dalvikvm(10252): No JNI_OnLoad found in libnativehelper.so 0x0, skipping init
03-25 18:52:16.031: D/dalvikvm(10252): Note: class Landroid/app/ActivityManagerNative; has 179 unimplemented (abstract) methods
03-25 18:52:16.721: E/memtrack(10252): Couldn't load memtrack module (No such file or directory)
03-25 18:52:16.721: E/android.os.Debug(10252): failed to load memtrack module: -2
03-25 18:52:17.191: D/AndroidRuntime(10252): Calling main entry com.android.commands.am.Am
03-25 18:52:17.271: I/ActivityManager(385): START u0 {act=android.intent.action.MAIN cat=[android.intent.category.LAUNCHER] flg=0x10000000 cmp=com.example.minimalbrowserx/.MainActivity} from pid 10252
03-25 18:52:17.281: D/AndroidRuntime(10252): Shutting down VM
03-25 18:52:17.291: D/jdwp(10252): Got wake-up signal, bailing out of select
03-25 18:52:17.291: D/dalvikvm(10252): Debugger has detached; object registry had 1 entries
03-25 18:52:25.101: W/AwContents(10213): nativeOnDraw failed; clearing to background color.
03-25 18:52:25.161: E/SoundPool(385): error loading /system/media/audio/ui/Effect_Tick.ogg
03-25 18:52:25.161: W/AudioService(385): Soundpool could not load file: /system/media/audio/ui/Effect_Tick.ogg
03-25 18:52:25.161: E/SoundPool(385): error loading /system/media/audio/ui/Effect_Tick.ogg
03-25 18:52:25.161: W/AudioService(385): Soundpool could not load file: /system/media/audio/ui/Effect_Tick.ogg
03-25 18:52:25.171: E/SoundPool(385): error loading /system/media/audio/ui/Effect_Tick.ogg
03-25 18:52:25.171: W/AudioService(385): Soundpool could not load file: /system/media/audio/ui/Effect_Tick.ogg
03-25 18:52:25.171: E/SoundPool(385): error loading /system/media/audio/ui/Effect_Tick.ogg
03-25 18:52:25.171: W/AudioService(385): Soundpool could not load file: /system/media/audio/ui/Effect_Tick.ogg
03-25 18:52:25.171: E/SoundPool(385): error loading /system/media/audio/ui/Effect_Tick.ogg
03-25 18:52:25.171: W/AudioService(385): Soundpool could not load file: /system/media/audio/ui/Effect_Tick.ogg
03-25 18:52:25.171: E/SoundPool(385): error loading /system/media/audio/ui/KeypressStandard.ogg
03-25 18:52:25.171: W/AudioService(385): Soundpool could not load file: /system/media/audio/ui/KeypressStandard.ogg
03-25 18:52:25.171: E/SoundPool(385): error loading /system/media/audio/ui/KeypressSpacebar.ogg
03-25 18:52:25.171: W/AudioService(385): Soundpool could not load file: /system/media/audio/ui/KeypressSpacebar.ogg
03-25 18:52:25.171: E/SoundPool(385): error loading /system/media/audio/ui/KeypressDelete.ogg
03-25 18:52:25.171: W/AudioService(385): Soundpool could not load file: /system/media/audio/ui/KeypressDelete.ogg
03-25 18:52:25.171: E/SoundPool(385): error loading /system/media/audio/ui/KeypressReturn.ogg
03-25 18:52:25.171: W/AudioService(385): Soundpool could not load file: /system/media/audio/ui/KeypressReturn.ogg
03-25 18:52:25.171: E/SoundPool(385): error loading /system/media/audio/ui/KeypressInvalid.ogg
03-25 18:52:25.171: W/AudioService(385): Soundpool could not load file: /system/media/audio/ui/KeypressInvalid.ogg
03-25 18:52:25.171: W/AudioService(385): onLoadSoundEffects(), Error -1 while loading samples
03-25 18:52:25.361: D/AndroidRuntime(10213): Shutting down VM
03-25 18:52:25.361: W/dalvikvm(10213): threadid=1: thread exiting with uncaught exception (group=0xb3acbba8)
03-25 18:52:25.381: E/AndroidRuntime(10213): FATAL EXCEPTION: main
03-25 18:52:25.381: E/AndroidRuntime(10213): Process: com.example.minimalbrowserx, PID: 10213
03-25 18:52:25.381: E/AndroidRuntime(10213): java.lang.NullPointerException
03-25 18:52:25.381: E/AndroidRuntime(10213):  at com.example.minimalbrowserx.MainActivity$1.onClick(MainActivity.java:105)
03-25 18:52:25.381: E/AndroidRuntime(10213):  at android.view.View.performClick(View.java:4438)
03-25 18:52:25.381: E/AndroidRuntime(10213):  at android.view.View$PerformClick.run(View.java:18422)
03-25 18:52:25.381: E/AndroidRuntime(10213):  at android.os.Handler.handleCallback(Handler.java:733)
03-25 18:52:25.381: E/AndroidRuntime(10213):  at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:95)
03-25 18:52:25.381: E/AndroidRuntime(10213):  at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:136)
03-25 18:52:25.381: E/AndroidRuntime(10213):  at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:5017)
03-25 18:52:25.381: E/AndroidRuntime(10213):  at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method)
03-25 18:52:25.381: E/AndroidRuntime(10213):  at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:515)
03-25 18:52:25.381: E/AndroidRuntime(10213):  at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:779)
03-25 18:52:25.381: E/AndroidRuntime(10213):  at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:595)
03-25 18:52:25.381: E/AndroidRuntime(10213):  at dalvik.system.NativeStart.main(Native Method)
03-25 18:52:25.401: W/ActivityManager(385):   Force finishing activity com.example.minimalbrowserx/.MainActivity
03-25 18:52:25.421: D/gralloc(54): Registering a buffer in the process that created it. This may cause memory ordering problems.
03-25 18:52:25.421: E/libEGL(54): called unimplemented OpenGL ES API
03-25 18:52:25.421: E/libEGL(54): called unimplemented OpenGL ES API
03-25 18:52:25.431: E/libEGL(54): called unimplemented OpenGL ES API
03-25 18:52:25.431: E/libEGL(54): called unimplemented OpenGL ES API
03-25 18:52:25.431: E/SurfaceFlinger(54): glCheckFramebufferStatusOES error 2139965326
03-25 18:52:25.431: E/SurfaceFlinger(54): got GL_FRAMEBUFFER_COMPLETE_OES error while taking screenshot
03-25 18:52:25.441: E/libEGL(54): called unimplemented OpenGL ES API
03-25 18:52:25.441: E/libEGL(54): called unimplemented OpenGL ES API
03-25 18:52:25.441: W/WindowManager(385): Screenshot failure taking screenshot for (246x410) to layer 21010
03-25 18:52:25.731: I/Choreographer(385): Skipped 37 frames!  The application may be doing too much work on its main thread.
03-25 18:52:26.241: W/ActivityManager(385): Activity pause timeout for ActivityRecord{b3dbeaa0 u0 com.example.minimalbrowserx/.MainActivity t135 f}
03-25 18:52:26.391: I/Choreographer(540): Skipped 32 frames!  The application may be doing too much work on its main thread.
03-25 18:52:28.141: E/SoundPool(385): error loading /system/media/audio/ui/Effect_Tick.ogg
03-25 18:52:28.141: W/AudioService(385): Soundpool could not load file: /system/media/audio/ui/Effect_Tick.ogg
03-25 18:52:28.141: E/SoundPool(385): error loading /system/media/audio/ui/Effect_Tick.ogg
03-25 18:52:28.151: W/AudioService(385): Soundpool could not load file: /system/media/audio/ui/Effect_Tick.ogg
03-25 18:52:28.151: E/SoundPool(385): error loading /system/media/audio/ui/Effect_Tick.ogg
03-25 18:52:28.151: W/AudioService(385): Soundpool could not load file: /system/media/audio/ui/Effect_Tick.ogg
03-25 18:52:28.151: E/SoundPool(385): error loading /system/media/audio/ui/Effect_Tick.ogg
03-25 18:52:28.151: W/AudioService(385): Soundpool could not load file: /system/media/audio/ui/Effect_Tick.ogg
03-25 18:52:28.151: E/SoundPool(385): error loading /system/media/audio/ui/Effect_Tick.ogg
03-25 18:52:28.151: W/AudioService(385): Soundpool could not load file: /system/media/audio/ui/Effect_Tick.ogg
03-25 18:52:28.151: E/SoundPool(385): error loading /system/media/audio/ui/KeypressStandard.ogg
03-25 18:52:28.151: W/AudioService(385): Soundpool could not load file: /system/media/audio/ui/KeypressStandard.ogg
03-25 18:52:28.151: E/SoundPool(385): error loading /system/media/audio/ui/KeypressSpacebar.ogg
03-25 18:52:28.151: W/AudioService(385): Soundpool could not load file: /system/media/audio/ui/KeypressSpacebar.ogg
03-25 18:52:28.151: E/SoundPool(385): error loading /system/media/audio/ui/KeypressDelete.ogg
03-25 18:52:28.161: W/AudioService(385): Soundpool could not load file: /system/media/audio/ui/KeypressDelete.ogg
03-25 18:52:28.161: E/SoundPool(385): error loading /system/media/audio/ui/KeypressReturn.ogg
03-25 18:52:28.161: W/AudioService(385): Soundpool could not load file: /system/media/audio/ui/KeypressReturn.ogg
03-25 18:52:28.161: E/SoundPool(385): error loading /system/media/audio/ui/KeypressInvalid.ogg
03-25 18:52:28.161: W/AudioService(385): Soundpool could not load file: /system/media/audio/ui/KeypressInvalid.ogg
03-25 18:52:28.161: W/AudioService(385): onLoadSoundEffects(), Error -1 while loading samples
03-25 18:52:28.231: I/Process(10213): Sending signal. PID: 10213 SIG: 9
03-25 18:52:28.311: I/ActivityManager(385): Process com.example.minimalbrowserx (pid 10213) has died.
03-25 18:52:28.371: W/InputDispatcher(385): channel 'b4213d88 com.example.minimalbrowserx/com.example.minimalbrowserx.MainActivity (server)' ~ Consumer closed input channel or an error occurred.  events=0x9
03-25 18:52:28.371: E/InputDispatcher(385): channel 'b4213d88 com.example.minimalbrowserx/com.example.minimalbrowserx.MainActivity (server)' ~ Channel is unrecoverably broken and will be disposed!
03-25 18:52:28.411: W/InputDispatcher(385): Attempted to unregister already unregistered input channel 'b4213d88 com.example.minimalbrowserx/com.example.minimalbrowserx.MainActivity (server)'
03-25 18:52:28.411: I/WindowState(385): WIN DEATH: Window{b4213d88 u0 com.example.minimalbrowserx/com.example.minimalbrowserx.MainActivity}
03-25 18:52:28.421: I/Choreographer(385): Skipped 34 frames!  The application may be doing too much work on its main thread.
03-25 18:52:28.501: I/Choreographer(385): Skipped 95 frames!  The application may be doing too much work on its main thread.
03-25 18:52:28.591: W/InputMethodManagerService(385): Got RemoteException sending setActive(false) notification to pid 10213 uid 10052
03-25 18:52:28.601: W/Binder(503): Caught a RuntimeException from the binder stub implementation.
03-25 18:52:28.601: W/Binder(503): java.lang.NullPointerException
03-25 18:52:28.601: W/Binder(503):  at android.inputmethodservice.IInputMethodWrapper.setSessionEnabled(IInputMethodWrapper.java:280)
03-25 18:52:28.601: W/Binder(503):  at com.android.internal.view.IInputMethod$Stub.onTransact(IInputMethod.java:129)
03-25 18:52:28.601: W/Binder(503):  at android.os.Binder.execTransact(Binder.java:404)
03-25 18:52:28.601: W/Binder(503):  at dalvik.system.NativeStart.run(Native Method)
03-25 18:52:28.691: I/Choreographer(385): Skipped 41 frames!  The application may be doing too much work on its main thread.
03-25 18:53:21.601: D/LightsService(385): Excessive delay setting light: 155ms
03-25 19:03:19.131: D/ConnectivityService(385): Sampling interval elapsed, updating statistics ..
03-25 19:03:19.181: D/ConnectivityService(385): Done.
03-25 19:03:19.181: D/ConnectivityService(385): Setting timer for 720seconds
03-25 19:04:19.181: I/ProcessStatsService(385): Prepared write state in 5ms
03-25 19:04:19.191: I/ProcessStatsService(385): Prepared write state in 10ms
```

Comment: LogCat Posted! Thank You

Answer (score 1, accepted):

According to your logcat it seems that you are calling `progress.setProgress(0)` (line 105) but you haven't instantiated the `progress` `ProgressBar` (therefore its value is `null`). This causes a `java.lang.NullPointerException`. Instantiate the `progress` `ProgressBar` before calling the `setProgress(0)` on it.

Comment: Sir you just figured out something that i was hitting my head for 2-3 days!!!  Just removed that line and it started working!!! :) I cant thank you enough!!!

Comment: Glad I could help. Also since you are new here, if this answer has solved your question please consider accepting it by clicking the check-mark. This indicates to the wider community that you've found a solution and gives some reputation to both the answerer and yourself.